# Why is my screen flickering while watching some flash videos?

Tags: 12.10, video, flash, flicker

I'm having an issue where on many flash videos (AMCTV's sites videos allow me to reproduce this consistantly) flicker.  The bottom half of my laptop or vga monitor's screen will flash white or turn black, then the same with the top.  This makes renders videos from certain sites unwatchable.

Comment: What browser are you using? Are you using the latest official flash plugin from Adobe, or the one that is built into the browser?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I experienced the same thing as you described.  It has to do with video card, not browser nor an application.  The flashing usually have to do with cpu when accessing video adapter.

So, instead, I made a modification on ONE line on my GRUB file `/etc/default/grub`

Look for this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

and edit to this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"
```

then save the file, then fire this command: `sudo update-grub && sudo reboot`

Explanation:
`nomodeset` = telling kernel to not load video adapter at boot up (so that way it'd let Ubuntu to take the full control of video adapter).  Ubuntu can have the control to that hardwares ONLY if they weren't touched by kernel.

Maybe this is the case in your situation?